# Remove unmatched records from list

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have a class ABC like this

```
public class ABC{
public int Id {get;set;}
public int UserCount {get;set;}
}
```

Now I add following records to a list of type ABC

```
List<ABC> lstABC = new List<ABC>();
lstABC.Add(new ABC(){Id=1,UserCount=5});
lstABC.Add(new ABC(){Id=2,UserCount=15});
lstABC.Add(new ABC(){Id=3,UserCount=3});
lstABC.Add(new ABC(){Id=4,UserCount=20});
lstABC.Add(new ABC(){Id=5,UserCount=33});
lstABC.Add(new ABC(){Id=6,UserCount=21});
```

I've another list of type int

```
List<int> lstIds = new List<int>();
lstIds.Add(1);
lstIds.Add(3);
lstIds.Add(4);
```

Now i want to remove all the items from `lstABC` whose Id's do not match in `lstIds` without using any loops. What is the most optimized way to do this?

Comment: LINQ is internally syntactical sugar of loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just use RemoveAll like this :

```
lstABC.RemoveAll(x => !lstIds.Contains(x.Id));
```

it should work easily

Answer (score 0):

Continuing @Coder1409 solution, use HashSet to boost performance (for big collections):

```
HashSet<int> hashSet = new HashSet<int>(lstIds);
lstABC.RemoveAll(x => !hashSet.Contains(x.Id));
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Another solution somewhat simpler to read

```
  lstABC = (from l in lstABC
                 where lstIds.Contains(l.Id)
                 select l).ToList();
```

Instead of removing you can also select only the matching elements